# Complex query in nHibernate using DetachedCriteria

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I'm currently trying to move from hand-crafted hql to queries constructed via DetachedCriteria. I have and HQL:

```
from GenericObject genericObject 
      left join fetch genericObject.Positions positions
      where (positions.Key.TrackedSourceID, positions.Key.PositionTimestamp) in 
      (select gp.Key.TrackedSourceID, max(gp.Key.PositionTimestamp)
       from GenericPosition gp 
group by gp.Key.TrackedSourceID)
```

Now using DetachedCriteria:

```
var subquery = DetachedCriteria
                .For (typeof (GenericPosition), "gp")
                .SetProjection (Projections.ProjectionList ()
                                    .Add (Projections.Property ("gp.Key.TrackedSourceID"))
                                    .Add (Projections.Max ("gp.Key.PositionTimestamp"))
                                    .Add (Projections.GroupProperty ("gp.Key.TrackedSourceID"))
                );
            var criteriaQuery = DetachedCriteria
                .For (typeof (GenericObject), "genericObject")
                .CreateAlias ("genericObject.Positions", "positions")
                .SetFetchMode ("genericObject.Positions", FetchMode.Eager)
                .Add (Subqueries.In (??, subquery))
```

I don't know what to type instead of ?? to create expression like (positions.Key.TrackedSourceID, positions.Key.PositionTimestamp)

Answer (score 3):

I cannot see the advantage in moving from hql to DetachedCriteria, if the latter is more difficult to write. And read.

In my projects I use preferrably DetachedCriteria, unless the syntax gets too complicated. Then I use hql. Until it gets complicated again. Then I give it a try in sql, and go back to hql if it doesn't improve readability.

Keep in mind that you will have to maintain these queries in the future.

Comment: Well you're right. However, I'm creating this query dynamically and called methods append something to the query. After the query is assembled, I need to append values for parameters and it's quite inelegant - DetachedCriteria seems like nicer solution here.

Comment: You are right, and I was hoping that your question would hold an answer,... I found myself ina similar situation...

Comment: I've a workaround for this - I'm just appending native SQL command to DetachedCriteria and it does the jiob. There is of course problem with names of the params but I'm using additional routines to determine name of the column in the database corresponding to a concrete property.

Answer (score 0):

HQL has lot of string manipulations done internally and hence may create memory issues as string is immutable type.  It is advisable to use DetachedCriteria instead of HQL.

Comment: If you have so many HQL queries that you have strings causing memory issues, I would hazard a guess that you're doing it wrong.